# C# C0246 While Filtering DataGridView with Listbox whose items come from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.7.2

I share with you a piece of code that works except the part where I'm trying to loop in the items of my listbox. That's why I'm here asking you for some help.
Lately, I switched from VBA to C# so I'm still new on this and don't undertsand everything yet.
So, the below code connect to my SQL server DB and fetch data both within my listbox and a DataGridView. I can filter with two textboxes also.
So now I have items within my listbox and my db's view within the DataGridview. I'd like to filter my DataGridview (which is filled by a datatable ) with my Listbox's item. I miss only a silly part I guess. Why Do I get this CS0246 "ListItem could not be found"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsAppTest
{

public partial class Form1 : Form

{
   //Initialize the component and display the items within my listbox CS_Bonds_listBox
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connetionString = @"Data Source=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_db;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT DISTINCT RatingProvider FROM Bonds", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        this.CS_Bonds_listBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.CS_Bonds_listBox.DisplayMember = "RatingProvider";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    DataTable dtTEST = new DataTable();

// Next, when clicking on my button Connect, I retrieve my db into a Datatable that is displayed within //the Datagridview1

    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = @"Data Source=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_db;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection cnn= new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
        String sql = "Select * from Bonds";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlDA.SelectCommand = command;
        sqlDA.Fill(dtTEST);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTEST;

        cnn.Close();
    }

    private void ISIN_Bonds_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dtTEST.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "ISIN LIKE '" + ISIN_Bonds_textBox.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }

    private void Ticker_Bonds_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv1 = dtTEST.DefaultView;
        dv1.RowFilter = "Ticker LIKE '" + Ticker_Bonds_textBox.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv1;
    }


    private void CS_Bonds_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conString = @"Data Source=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_db;Integrated Security=SSPI";           
        string query = "SELECT ISIN, Ticker, CrediSight, FROM Bonds";
        string condition = string.Empty;

        foreach (ListItem item in CS_Bonds_listBox.Items)
        {
            condition += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
        {
            condition = string.Format(" WHERE Country IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
        }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        //dataGridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you make sure that all code lines have at least 4 spaces at the start then they will appear well formatted on stackoverflow

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks, should be better now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line has a problem:

```
foreach (ListItem item in CS_Bonds_listBox.Items)
```

A ListItem is a WebForms thing, and your application is a WinForms thing; your listbox doesn't contain a list of ListItem objects so this line of code wouldn't work out anyway, even if the relevant web namespace was imported.

Because you've bound your listbox to a datatable the list it is showing is full of DataRowView objects, so that's what you need to process. A DataRowView has a Row property that gives you the underlying row, which in turn can be accessed by a column name.

Additionally, to make your life easier a listbox has a SelectedItems property so you don't need to check every item for being selected:

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in CS_Bonds_listBox.SelectedItems)
{
  var dr = drv.Row as DataRow;
  var rp = dr["RatingProvider"]; 
  condition += $"'{rp}'," 
}
```

Your condition will end up with a trailing comma as a result of this, so trim it off before you build an IN clause with it:

```
condition = condition.TrimEnd(',');
```

---

This technique could be susceptible to SQL Injection hacking if the user manages to change the text showing in the list items.

A better way to handle the problem is via parameterization. You'd do it like this:

```
var cmd  = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Country IN(", connStr);

int i = 0;
foreach (DataRowView drv in CS_Bonds_listBox.SelectedItems)
{
  var dr = drv.Row as DataRow;
  var rp = dr["RatingProvider"]; 
  cmd.CommandText += $"@p{i},";
  cmd.Parameters.Add($"@p{i}", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rp;
  i++;
}

cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
  var dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(dt);
  someGridView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This builds an sql that looks like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Country IN(@p0,@p1,@p2....` i.e. we have concatenated parameter placeholders in rather than concatenating values in. At the same time we have filled the parameters collection with the parameter values

It also means that our database can't be [hacked via our program](https://bobby-tables.com), and our app doesn't die in a heap when the user selects a country with a name like `Cote d'Ivoire`

---

Some other things to note to tidy your code up:

SqlDataAdapter can take a string SQL and a string connection-string. You don't need to make a SqlCommand for it. You don't need to open and close conenctions for it; it knows how to do all this itself. I only used a SqlCommand because I was building the parameters collection as I went. Ordinarily I'd do `using(var da = SqlDataAdapter("SELECT...", "Server=..")` because it makes things nice and tidy.

This means e.g. your constructor can be simply:

```
//put this here once
private string _connStr = @"Data Source=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_db;Integrated Security=SSPI";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    var dt = new DataTable();
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT RatingProvider FROM Bonds", _connStr))
      adapter.Fill(dt);
    this.CS_Bonds_listBox.DataSource = dt;
    this.CS_Bonds_listBox.DisplayMember = "RatingProvider";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your advices it is gold ! Nice French plus :) 
However, I have some questions though. First, How do you manage to know if it's a WebForms or a WinForms object ? 

Your proposition was definitely  more logic than mine so  I made the change but the weird thing is, as soon as I run the app, it crashes directly on the last line "sda.Fill(dt) and warns about a parenthesis wrongly put but it's like the code put all the items directly in the condition whitout even let me clik or select one of them.I hope it's clear enough ...

Comment: For webforms/winforms I recognize most of them these days but if I don't then a quick google "ListItem class" gives it - think google has realized long ago that I'm a software dev because the first hit is MSDN :) and at the top of the page is the namespace System.Web.UI.. I didn't quite get the other problem. Are you saying your program crashes with an error message when it is running? Or that you see a red wavy line under your code works? What is the exact meteor message (in either case)?

Comment: @CaiuJard , Thanks for answering man, I still need to get along with this Microsoft help obviously !
I'll double check my error message and get back to you after work. Apologies for my late reply.

Comment: Hey @Caius Jard at last I could connect and test. Here is my error messgae so I guess it's in the string condition that there is something:

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Underperform)'.
Incorrect syntax near 'Underperform)'.'

But the thing is, why is it running the filter when I start the app and not when I'm checking the boxes

Comment: Probably because the event you've hooked up to is no good for what you need.. Use a different event on listbox?

Comment: I used "SelectedIndexChanged", you porbably right, I'll check which one can fit better

Comment: Btw, it was the "checking the boxes" bit that confused me; are you using a CheckedListBox? The code I gave is for a ListBox which relies on selecting (blue highlight) not checking (ticking in a small square). It is normal for list controls to fire events stating that a selected index has change, upon start up of a form. Program your code to be tolerant of it

Comment: I confirm it's a listbox

Comment: When I try to change the event I got this: 
Error CS1061 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'CS_Bonds_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged' and no accessible extension method 'CS_Bonds_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sounds like you've deleted or renamed your `CS_Bonds_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged` method to something else, but the forms designer is still configered to use that event, so the event binding code in Form1.Designer.cs is out of date. If you have renamed the method, open `Form.Designer.cs` and remove the line that looks like `CS_Bonds_listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += CS_Bonds_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;` - it'll have a red wiggly line under it, and then open the forms designer and bind a different event

Comment: @Caisu Jard sorry if it sounds silly but within my code the _SelectedIndexChanged part is the event ofCS_Bonds_listBox right ? Because at the end, looks like  CS_Bonds_listBox.SelectedIndexChanged is a method within the class Form1

Comment: An event is simply "a list of methods that shall be called when thing X happens". If you type `listbox.` you can see the intellisense has a `⚡ SelectedIndexChanged` - this is the event "placeholder list". If you then write `listbox.SelectedIndexChanged += myMethodName` it will "add `myMethodName` to the "list of methods that must be called when the event occurs". And so event handling is merely attaching your own methods to something; you can attach multiple, they get called in an undefined order. To be compatible your method *must* have a signature that matches some requirement..

Comment: For `SelectedIndexChanged` "any method that has a first argument of type `object` and a second argument to which an `EventArgs`  is assignable, is compatible. By default when you pick an event in the windows forms designer it creates a method called `ControlNameHere_EventNameHere(...)` but you can rename it if you wish. If you do rename it after creation then you have to change the code where the windows forms designer wired it up to the old name, so that it reflects the new. Renaming the method does NOT change which event it binds to. `button.Click += Form1_MouseMove` binds a click handler to

Comment: a method called Form1.MouseMove. Every time the button is clicked, `Form1_MouseMove` will be called. The name of the method has no meaning at all in terms of which event it handles. Which event it handles is defined by what is on the left hand side of the `+=`